# How to convert conditions in .htaccess file to web.config

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, web-config

I have this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ rewrite.php
```

How do I rewrite this in a web.config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/admin/" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{THE_REQUEST}" pattern="^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="rewrite.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```